# Find all usernames in the likes of some photo in Instagram

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm not sure if I asked the question correctly.
I try to find all instagram profiles liked given post. Like list of them. To use them for statistic in my app. Is it possible to do it with the Instagram API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sory, but is too complain, isn't possible with the Instagram api. Is possible with a server and a brother simulation.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the answer! Can you give me some clarification for what "brother simulation" is?

Comment: You simulate a brother for go on instagram.com, you simulate a human for login and you get and analyse the HTML code for find your data. You vans search that width js id. Can you give a point for my commentary ?

Comment: It's really too complex. I know there are many telegram groups which do that to trace who from the users likes posts and who doesn't. I'm in such a group. I'm wondering if they do it this way too..